# Height of inputs in bootstrap grids

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I have some troubles with the height of some input fields in a form. The form layout is based on bootstrap's grid. Each input is paired with a label onto its left (unless the screen is too small, in that case all the form content would be stacked vertically). If the label is long enough, it's split among multiple rows, but if that happens, the height of all the inputs on the same row increase. There is a way to fix the height of inputs with bootstrap classes?

**Remark**: I know how to fix with CSS, i want to know if there is a way using only Bootstrap

**An example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input1">Label 1</label>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-9">
        <span class="input-group-addon">1</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input2">Label 2 is very long and could occupy more than 1 row</label>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-9">
        <span class="input-group-addon">2</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In this case I want that `input2` has the same height of `input1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the `input-group` `col-sm-*` divs into nested divs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input1">Label 1</label>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-9">
        <span class="input-group-addon">1</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input2">Label 2 is very long and could occupy more than 1 row</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">2</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Extra**
To vertically align the div and the label the classes `align-items-*` for `row` divs or `align-self-*` for `col` div can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `input-group` from the col around the inputs.

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input1">Label 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3" for="input2">Label 2 is very long and could occupy more than 1 row</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added a more complex example. The fact is that I need the class input group because in my project I added a span after the input inside the input-group. I will update the example ASAP (I'm not in front of a PC right now).